# Using HAproxy to redirect incoming traffic to docker

Tags: docker, haproxy

We are currently using HAproxy to redirect incoming traffic to our domain `example.domain` to our containers, which are only accessible via the local interface (e.g. `127.0.0.1:12000:8080`

To achieve this our current config looks something like this:

```
defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout check 5000
    timeout client 20000
    timeout server 20000

frontend domain
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain.cert
    bind *:11000-11199 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain.cert
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc } # ssl_fc returns true if the request is already using SSL
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    
    # Ports 11000-11099 are reserved for secure traffic
    acl secure_0_host dst_port 11000
    acl secure_1_host dst_port 11001

    # Ports 11100-11199 are reserved for insecure traffic
    acl insecure_0_host dst_port 11100
    acl insecure_1_host dst_port 11101

    # Secure Backends
    use_backend secure_0 if secure_0_host
    use_backend secure_1 if secure_1_host

    # Insecure Backends
    use_backend insecure_0 if insecure_0_host
    use_backend insecure_1 if insecure_1_host

    # Fallback Backend
    default_backend fallback_backend

backend fallback_backend
    http-request redirect location https://example.domain code 302

# Secure Backends
backend secure_0
    server secure_0 127.0.0.1:12000 ssl verify none

backend secure_1
    server secure_1 127.0.0.1:12001 ssl verify none


# Insecure Backends
backend insecure_0
    server insecure_0 127.0.0.1:12100

backend insecure_1
    server insecure_1 127.0.0.1:12101
```

This setup does work but it is really tedious to manually add each port-mapping and also it kinda bugs me, that I have to use different ports (`12000-12099`) for the docker containers, than I am listening on with HAproxy.

Is it somehow possible to just tell the config, that a given portrange (`11000-11099`) should be passed through to `127.0.0.1:11000-11099`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794547/how-to-configure-haproxy-port-range-to-range-one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

can try this https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/configuration/binds/syntax/ which is slightly different than using the port range for acls ... or just have different front ends for each port range like that docs shows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).